# Finding Jordan Canonical form given the minimal polynomial and the dimension of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

How can we find the Jordan Canonical form given the minimal polynomial and the dimension of the kernel? I know how we could find it if either the matrix or the characteristic polynomial was given, but how does knowing the dimension of the kernel help us?
$$
B: \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4
$$
$$
m_B(x) = (x-2)^2*x
$$

$$\newcommand{\Ker}{{\operatorname{Ker}}}
\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\Ker(B)=2
$$

Using the minimal polynomial I found that the Jordan form should be either

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I suppose that the statement about the kernel should tell us which of this matrices is the right one. (assuming I found the right matrices in the first place :) )

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: The fact that the dimension of the kernel is $2$ tells you that you can find two linearly independent vectors in the kernel; but the kernel is nothing but the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin.  Your comment was very helpful.

Comment: BTW you can use `$(x-2)^2\cdot x$` $(x-2)^2\cdot x$ instead of $(x-2)^2*x$. (Possibly also $(x-2)^2x$. Depending on which one looks better to you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on this case, the minimal polynomial implies that the elementary factors includes $(x-2)^2$ and $x$.

Plus we know $\dim\ker B=2$, which means $0$ is the double root of the characteristic polynomial.

So the Jordan block is in correspondence with $x$, $x$, $(x-2)^2$. Hence, the **first** one is right.

In general cases, it's customary to consider **the minimal polynomial** to get the biggest *invariant factors to control other factors*. Second, calculate the **determinant factors**. Calculate the **geometric multiplicity** of any eigenvalues is also helpful, which implies the *numbers of Jordan bloc*k of each eigenvalues.

Hope my answer will be helpful. I can offer some examples using these methods if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that $X(X-2)^2$ is the minimal polynomial gives you two kinds of information: (1) the (only) eigenvalues are $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=2$ (the roots of the minimal polynomial), and (2) the part of the Jordan normal form for the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is diagonal (i.e., the all blocks for $\lambda=0$ are of size$~1$, the multiplicity of the root$~0$), while for the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ the largest Jordan block has size$~2$ (the multiplicity of the root$~2$). This indeed leaves open the two options you mentioned, but if it is given that the kernel (which is none other than the eigenspace for $\lambda=0$) is of dimension$~2$, then it becomes clear that there must be two Jordan blocks (of size$~1$) for this eigenvalue, your first option.